# Detect whether a FIFO is closed in C using poll()

Tags: c

I have been researching around using poll() to detect whether an FIFO has been closed from another process, but haven't been able to get anything to work. The polling section of my code is as follows:

```
            int poll_return = poll(pfds, 2, POLL_TIMEOUT);
            printf("POLL CALLED\n");

            if (pfds[0].revents != 0) {
                printf("Events: %d%d%d\n", 
                (pfds[0].revents & POLLIN), 
                (pfds[0].revents & POLLHUP), 
                (pfds[0].revents & POLLERR));

                if (pfds[0].revents & POLLHUP) {
                    printf("FIFO has been closed");
                }
            }
```

For some reason, the code prints:

POLL CALLED

Events: 000

Comment: Please post a [mre].  2nd step print out `poll_return` & `errno`

Comment: You can tell it's been closed because reading from it will start to indicate end of file after you've read all remaining data in the pipe buffer (It'll poll as readable).

Comment: I see the same behavior on macOS 12.3.1. The `poll()` does not return when the other (write) end of the FIFO is closed. On Linux it does return properly.